# Apache rewrite work on http, but not working on https

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, mod-rewrite

I am using apache 2.2, trying to make rewrite from one url subdomain to another domain, it is working properly on http vhost, but on https not working at all

/etc/apache2/domain1.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName *.domain1.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1

            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.
            RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.domain2 [R=301,L]
    ..........
    ......
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName *.domain1.com

            DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.
            RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.domain2 [R=301,L]
    .......
    </VirtualHost>
```

Any Help please?

Comment: Do you have `SSL` setup on the server?

Comment: I don't see a `mod_ssl.c` module wrapper around your site!

Comment: Yes, i have it and the ssl is working proberly, i just shortcut the config, as the ssl is not my issue, my issue is rewrite

Comment: Wrap it with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> </IfModule>` and lets see, and add `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Comment: Didn't work either, http working and redirecting normally, but https not redirecting